# Web3js smart contract interaction gas and signing

Tags: javascript, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

So I can interact with a function within a smart contract.
I also know that to actually do the transaction I need something like this:

`const contractObj = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress)`

`const transaction= await contractObj .methods.NameofTheMethod(x).send({from:myAddress,gasLimit:value})`

My question is: what is the next step? Because I put myAddress but I should sign this before send the transaction right?

Otherwise how will it be able to take the fee from the gas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the private key of the `myAddress` to the web3 instance using the `wallet.add()` method ([docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-eth-accounts.html#wallet-add)). Web3 then signs the transaction before it's sent to a public node.

During local development, most node emulators (such as Ganache and Hardhat) contain private keys to the generated addresses. So in this case, the transaction is signed on the development node, and you don't need to sign it with your local web3 instance.

Comment: So if I pass the private key using wallet.add() I dont need to do additional steps and my transaction will be posted on the blockchain? No additiona steps to interact with this function?

Additionaly, how do I pass a a value that is a bool in the function? As 1 or true? Or boolean variable?

Comment: @JonhSnow Correct - no additional steps. Your node provider accepts the signed transaction and broadcasts it to the network... Ad bool: I'm not sure about TypeScript, so this might only apply to the "regular" JavaScript: Any "true-like" JS value (e.g. `1` or `true` or `"foo"`) is encoded to the corresponding "true" ABI hex value (63 zeros followed by a `1`) while generating the `data` field. TypeScript might require you to pass a `boolean`.